# Como integrar o React em uma estrutura MVC (PHP)?

Tags: php, mvc, react

Estou aprendendo PHP e me veio uma dúvida: Com o React, nós temos a CLI, que é uma estrutura já pronta para você, com todos os arquivos necessários. No MVC nós construímos uma estrutura separando a view, controller e model em pastas diferentes.

A dúvida é: Na estrutura MVC, eu devo baixar o pacote CLI do React para poder usá-lo, ou apenas copiar a CDN para as views e usá-lo normalmente?

Answer (score 1):

o ideal seria transformar seu código php em uma API REST. Essa API retornaria apenas os dados em JSON sem view, que serão utilizados no react.

Você teria seu controller baseado em retornos de JSON, exemplo:

```
public function index() {
  $dados = []; # qualquer dado

  http_response_code(200);
  return json_encode($dados);
}
```

No react, você pode usar a biblioteca [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), para fazer as requisições na API - php.